# How to change security configutarion in IE8 for Intranet pages, such that Javascript can close a Window without asking?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am developing a system that uses a little Internet page as a front-end for the whole program. Since I need to use ActiveX (sigh), the page must work on Internet Explorer.

However, after some actions have been done the page needs to close itself. Using `window.close()` on Javascript it works, but before closing it prompts the user if it wants to close the Window. The ideal would be that it closes automatically.

Is there any way to make IE8 (changing an option on the browser, not a code-only solution) not to prompt before closing the Window?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't an option that controls this.  You can try putting it in the trusted zone and see.  When you're ready to just make your ActiveX control do it (which involves writing a few lines of code), let me know and I'll tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

You must have the Windows Administrator mark the domain that the intranet site runs on as a trusted domain. That will set the site to run in "trusted" mode which will allow Javascript to run normally and things like NTLM authentication to be used.